# ¿como mostrar una notificación al intentar apagar Debian desde el entorno de escritorio?

Tags: python, linux, debian

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación que bloquee el apagado y muestre una notificación cuando el usuario intenta apagar con un pendrive conectado.

En otras distribuciones, lo he conseguido usando polkit, con un fichero .rules que invoque a un script; pero en Debian, la versión de polkit (0.105) no admite esos ficheros y solo permite el uso de fichero .pkla, los cuales no permiten invocar a scripts.

Mi fichero pkla es este:

```
[Shutdown]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.consolekit.system.stop; org.freedesktop.login1.power-off;org.freedesktop.login1.power-off-multiple-sessions;org.xfce.session.xfsm-shutdown-helper
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=no
```

Con esto he logrado bloquear el apagado, pero no puedo mostrar la notificación.

Se me ha ocurrido que podría usar un cliente dbus, lanzado por el usuario, que esté conectado a los eventos de apagado del sistema, pero no consigo que funcione.

He probado con este código:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from gi.repository import GLib
from gi.repository import Notify
import dbus
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop

dbus_loop = DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
bus = dbus.SystemBus(mainloop=dbus_loop)
loop = GLib.MainLoop()

def msg_handler(*args,**keywords):
    try:
         #show notification to desktop
         Notify.init('Pendrive Reminder')
         notify = Notify.Notification.new('Pendrive Reminder', 'Shutdown lock enabled. Disconnect pendrive to enable shutdown')
         notify.show()
     except:
        pass

 bus.add_signal_receiver(handler_function=msg_handler,dbus_interface='org.freedesktop.login1.power-off-multiple-sessions', path_keyword='path')
```

Pero, cuando lo ejecuto, con:

```
python client.py
```

me salta este error:

```
 ValueError: Invalid interface or error name 'org.freedesktop.login1.power-off-multiple-sessions': contains invalid character '-'
```

¿como podría detectar el evento desde dbus?

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Siguiendo las recomendaciones aportadas en las respuestas, he cambiado la captura del evento. El código resultante es el siguiente:

```
from gi.repository import GLib
from gi.repository import Notify
import dbus
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop

dbus_loop = DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
bus = dbus.SessionBus(mainloop=dbus_loop)
loop = GLib.MainLoop()

def msg_handler(*args,**keywords):
   try:
        #show notification to desktop
        Notify.init('Pendrive Reminder')
        notify = Notify.Notification.new('Pendrive Reminder', 'Shutdown lock enabled. Disconnect pendrive to enable shutdown')
        notify.show()
    except:
        pass

bus.add_signal_receiver(
    handler_function=msg_handler, 
    signal_name='PreparingForShutdown',
    dbus_interface='org.freedesktop.login1.Manager', 
    bus_name='org.freedesktop.login1'
)

bus.add_signal_receiver(
    handler_function=msg_handler, 
    signal_name='CanPowerOff',
    dbus_interface='org.freedesktop.login1.Manager', 
    bus_name='org.freedesktop.login1'
)

bus.add_signal_receiver(
    handler_function=msg_handler, 
    signal_name='PowerOff',
    dbus_interface='org.freedesktop.login1.Manager', 
    bus_name='org.freedesktop.login1'
)

loop.run()
```

Con esto ya no me da error de sintaxis, pero tampoco logro capturar la señal: cuando pulso el botón de apagado, no se muestra la notificación.

¿donde podría estar el error?

De hecho, tampoco lo encuentro en la lista de procesos en ejecución

**ACTUALIZACIÓN 2**

Usando `dbus-monitor --system` he descubierto que la acción realizada para bloquear el apagado es la siguiente:

```
signal time=1523017240.291438 sender=:1.16 -> destination=(null destination) serial=794 path=/org/freedesktop/login1; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties; member=PropertiesChanged
   string "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager"
   array [
      dict entry(
         string "DelayInhibited"
         variant             string "shutdown:sleep"
      )
   ]
   array [
   ]
```

He intentado capturarla con pydbus así:

```
from pydbus import SystemBus
from gi.repository import GLib
from gi.repository import Notify
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop

bus = SystemBus()

# Create an object that will proxy for a particular remote object.
power = bus.get('org.freedesktop.login1', '/org/freedesktop/login1')
loop = GLib.MainLoop()


if power.PropertiesChanged() == True:
    #show notification to desktop
    Notify.init('Pendrive Reminder')
    notify = Notify.Notification.new('Pendrive Reminder', 'Shutdown lock enabled. Disconnect pendrive to enable shutdown')
    notify.show()


loop.run()
```

Pero ahora me devuelve este error:

```
 AttributeError: 'ProxySignal' object has no attribute 'emit'
```

Creo que el problema es que la señal devuelve una estructura, en vez de un booleano, pero no sé como podría recrear la estructura en Python

¿alguna idea?

Comment: hace tiempo tuve que hacer algo similar y me centré en DBUS y la inhibición de señales. Hay más información aquí: http://www.devtech.com/inhibitapplet Si buscas como inhibir señales en dbus tendrás una lista bastante grande de las opciones según el gestor de escritorio que utilices porque algunos implementan más llamadas DBUS que otros. saludos,
n1mh

Comment: @n1mh Si no me equivoco, los eventos a capturar son los mismos que capturo desde polkit

Answer (score 1):

Me temo que el problema está en el nombre que has usado para la interfaz. Los guiones medios no estan permitidos para ellas, según las instrucciones de Freedesktop.org:

[D-BUS Valid names](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#message-protocol-names)

Si consultas estas directrices, verás que los nombres usados para interfaces, buses y miembros tienen ciertas características comunes:

- Un máximo de 255 caracteres.
- Cada elemento puede contener caracteres alfanuméricos, tanto mayúsculas como minúsculas, pero no puede empezar por número.
- Tienen que contener al menos un punto (.), pero no puede ser el carácter inicial.

Pero igualmente tienen ciertas restricciones:

- Las interfaces no pueden contener guiones medios, mientras que los nombre de buses si los admiten.

Mi recomendación sería usar el nombre de la interfaz ya conocida `org.freedesktop.login1`.

Más información al respecto en freedesktop.org :

[logind](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/logind/)

[DBUS tutorial](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-tutorial.html#interfaces)

Comment: Hola! gracias por la respuesta. Mira por favor [answer] para dejarla un poco mas completa. Este sitio no es como los otros (bah, son todos distintos) asi que te recomiendo que hagas el [tour], y de paso, si puedes, agrega la informacion importante de ese link en tu respuesta para que sea mejor recibida. Saludos!

Comment: @gbianchi. Listo, saludos.

Comment: El nombre que he usado para la interfaz es el del evento de apagado, que entiendo que es el mismo que capturo con polkit. No he creado ningún servidor dbus nuevo, es el nombre que tiene predefinido logind para dicho evento

Comment: @bitseater he respondido a tu sugerencia

Comment: @AlmuHS, estás usando un nombre de evento para la interfaz. Creo que no es correcto. Has creado un cliente para conectar al demonio `logind`. Este tiene una interfaz DBUS ya conocida, que es `org.freedesktop.login1`. Tu estás usando un método de esa interfaz para nombrarla (añadiendo detrás una cadena con caracteres inválidos). Creo que ocurre que el sistema verifica primero que el nombre es correcto (y no lo es y te arroja un fallo). Luego, si fuera correcto, ya trataría de conectar con él. Prueba con ese nombre para la interfaz (org.freedesktop.login1). Lo siento, no conozco bien Python ...

Comment: ... para ayudarte con el código, pero entiendo que el nombre de la interfaz debe ser ése. Me he peleado algo con DBUS para poder empaquetar en snapd y he leído sobre la selección del nombre de la interfaz.

Comment: gracias, lo probaré. Pero logind tiene muchos eventos ¿como identifico el que me interesa?

Comment: Puedes usar los métodos PowerOff(), Reboot(), Suspend(), Hibernate(), HybridSleep() . Mira la info en la página de logind que he enlazado.

Comment: @bitseater he actualizado la información

Comment: @AlmuHS, el código en Python no lo manejo en profundidad. En cuanto a la señal y la llamada `PropertiesChanged` lo que devuelve entiendo es la ID del objecto y el path del objecto. Fíjate en [logind](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/logind/) , sección **Signals** , donde habla de los eventos de apagado, dice *"..The SessionNew(), SessionRemoved(), UserNew(), UserRemoved(), SeatNew(), SeatRemoved() signals are sent each time a session is created or removed, a user logs in or out, or a seat is added or removed. They each contain the ID of the object plus the object path. .."*